# pySpark take() returns error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to learn pySpark.
I run these following commands:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .master("local") \
   .appName("Linear Regression Model - 2") \
   .config("spark.executor.memory", "1gb") \
   .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

print(sc)
```

It's ok and returns:

> SparkContext master=local appName=Linear Regression Model - 2

Then, I read a text file and show its values:

```
header = sc.textFile('cal_housing.domain')
header.collect()
```

The input files I got from here: [link](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~ltorgo/Regression/cal_housing.tgz)

It works just fine with the following output:

> ['longitude: continuous.',  'latitude: continuous.', 
>   'housingMedianAge: continuous. ',  'totalRooms: continuous. ', 
>   'totalBedrooms: continuous. ',  'population: continuous. ', 
>   'households: continuous. ',  'medianIncome: continuous. ', 
>   'medianHouseValue: continuous. ']

As I know, if we have a large data size, we should you ***take()*** instead. But, when I use ***take()*** function, it returns an error:

```
header.take(2)
```

I try to figure out why it returns ***TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable*** but I counldn't. As far as I understand, ***header*** is a **RDD object**, it contains a list of headers. Hence, it should iterable and not be an ***int***.

How to solve this error:

Error message:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 3.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver):
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 167, in main
>       func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)   File
>   "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 56, in read_command
>       command = serializer._read_with_length(file)   File "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 169, in _read_with_length
>       return self.loads(obj)   File "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 455, in loads
>       return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)   File "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 784, in _make_skel_func
>       closure = _reconstruct_closure(closures) if closures else None   File
>   "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 776, in _reconstruct_closure
>       return tuple([_make_cell(v) for v in values]) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:153)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:64)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1533)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1521)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1520)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1520)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1748)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1703)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1692)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:463)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 167, in main
>       func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)   File
>   "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 56, in read_command
>       command = serializer._read_with_length(file)   File "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 169, in _read_with_length
>       return self.loads(obj)   File "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 455, in loads
>       return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)   File "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 784, in _make_skel_func
>       closure = _reconstruct_closure(closures) if closures else None   File
>   "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 776, in _reconstruct_closure
>       return tuple([_make_cell(v) for v in values]) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.(PythonRDD.scala:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:153)
>     at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:64)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

Comment: This error is not what you described as the problem.

Comment: @abunickabhi: can you please point out what i'm missing. thank you

Comment: Please double check your paths. Looks like you submit with Spark 2.3 but using Spark 2.2 Python library.

Comment: printdoc: I think your problem is what @user6910411 suggested. To make it clear: It's likely that you're using 2 pysparks, 1 from Spark standalone cluster (spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7 in your log) and the other is got via "pip install pyspark". Read more at: https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/ (Note Section).

Comment: Thanks @abunickabhi and Catbuilts. I remove one in the two sparks and it worked. Thanks again